# How to repeat a text box horizontally in active reports 8, 9

Tags: c#, .net, activereports

I am having a text box that prints details of a person. The details of say, 10 people are getting displayed one below the other in the output page. I am trying to have these details to be printed side by side. Example, for details of 10 people, each row will have details of 2 people so, that will make it 5 rows. The same text box to be repeated horizontally and then continue likewise in next row. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired results using Section Based Report and setting the [ColumnCount](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/index.html#GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v9%7EGrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Detail%7EColumnCount.html) property for the detail section to 2. Once you set this property, you need to set the [ColumnDirection](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v9%7EGrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.ColumnDirection.html) property to "AcrossDown" so that the data is generated row by row instead of column by column.

I would also suggest you to check [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/arWLKColumnarReports.html) and [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/arWLKAddressLabels.html) walkthrough to see how this property is used.